# Cardinality of all compact metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, cardinals

I'm looking for cardinal number of all compact metric spaces. 
I know that:

1. Cardinal number of compact set is at most $\mathfrak{c}$ (it is a continous image of Cantor set)
2. Compact metric space is separable and complete, so we can look just at countable dense set. It bound our cardinal number to cardinality of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ which is $\mathfrak{c}$

How can I bound it from below?

Comment: Every finite metric space is compact. Are you perhaps interested only in the cardinality of infinite compact metric spaces?

Comment: There are of course countably infinite metric spaces too, for instance the one-point closure of the naturals.

Comment: Are you asking for the possible cardinalities of compact metric spaces?  Obviously they can be finite, countable, or have cardinality that of $\mathbb{R}$.  I guess you are saying they can't have higher cardinality.  I didn't understand your argument.  Maybe someone else can explain?

Comment: I`m looking for cardinality of set of all compact metric spaces, with homeomorphism as equivalence relation, not a cardinality of just compact metric spaces. I think that i found the upper limit of it: continuum. Am i wrong with conlcusions? 

Now im trying to find if continuum is really a number of all compact metric spaces. 

I`m sorry for bad english. I`m doing my best.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602978/how-many-closed-subsets-of-mathbb-r-are-there-up-to-homeomorphism for some ways of constructing $\mathfrak{c}$ non-homeomorphic compact metric spaces (specifically, subsets of $\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

There is no **set** of all compact metric spaces, because every singleton is a compact metric space, and the collection of all singletons is not a set.

However, note that every compact metric space is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of the Hilbert cube. So if you are only interested in equivalence classes of compact metric spaces, it suffices to consider subspaces of the Hilbert cube.

Comment: Why are compact metric spaces homeomorphic to subspaces of the Hilbert cube?

Comment: Well, that's a nontrivial proof. Every Polish space is a $G_\delta$ subspace of the Hilbert cube, and every compact metric space is Polish; but a compact subspace of the Hilbert cube is closed so it suffices to talk about closed subspaces (in the other direction, note that every closed subspace of the Hilbert cube is a compact metric space).